# Comparing Power of SRS to Block Randomization

Tags: experiment-design, random-allocation, blocking

I am trying to figure out how to run/analyze a block randomized experiment in the following situation, and to figure out how much of an improvement I would get over simple random sampling:

Suppose I have an email list of 30 people (10 adults and 20 children). I want to do an A/B test where I send two different emails and see which one people are more likely to open.  I assume that age is associated with the probability of opening an email, but I don't have prior estimates of what the open rates will be for the different groups.

I could do a block design to make sure there are exactly 5 adults and 10 children in each treatment group, or I could just divide up the 30 people completely randomly (ignoring whether they are adults or children).

I assume the change in power between the SRS design and the block design is a function of the correlation between open rate and the adult/child variable, but I can't figure out how to calculate this. I'd love to see how you can derive this relationship or how it could be calculated via simulations in R.

Secondly, assuming that I do use the block design. What is the best way to analyze the results that take the design into account?  Examples in R would be particularly appreciated.